# How to specify extra TZ info for 'apt-get install -y awscli'

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I want to install awscli onto my ubuntu docker image.

This is the command I used

```
apt-get install -y awscli
```

Shortly after the installation commenced, it prompted

> ### Configuring tzdata
>
> Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent
>   configuration questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of
>   cities, representing the time zones in which they are located.
>
> 1. Africa  2. America  3. Antarctica  4. Australia  5. Arctic  6. Asia  7. Atlantic  8. Europe  9. Indian  10. Pacific  11. SystemV  12.
>      US  13. Etc Geographic area:

Since I want to include this `apt-get` step in Docker, it cannot be interactive.

How can I pass this timezone info to `apt-get` and/or `aws-cli`?

I have tried to set the content of '/etc/timezone' to `Australia/Sydney`, but the prompt still comes up. If I kill the process at this point, I can see the content of the file '/etc/timezone' is changed to `Etc/UTC`

Comment: If it isn't installing `tzdata` as part of the `apt-get` process, then simply make the `/etc/timezone` file with the correct data in it (eg, `America/New York`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not work. I have add more details to the question.

Comment: OK... sorry, trying to get your timezone configured manually before.  Found it I think - https://serverfault.com/a/689947/389571 - if the timezone is set properly for what the docker can see before your apt-get call is made it should all just work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to a aws configuration file (e.g. `/root/.aws/credentials`) before running `pip install awscli`

```
region = us-west-2
```

Of course you should set the region to whatever makes sense for your project.

Answer (score 4):

The selected solution did not work for me, so I used this:

- export TZ=Europe/Paris
- ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
- apt install -y awscli

The following resource helped me: https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes

Answer (score 0):

You may also just install the awscli with `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y awscli
```

It will just select the default timezone for tzdata, which seems to be UTC as the install process prints out

```
Current default time zone: 'Etc/UTC'
Local time is now:      Fri Feb 23 18:12:49 UTC 2024.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Feb 23 18:12:49 UTC 2024.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.
```

The noninteractive means:

```
   noninteractive
          This is the anti-frontend. It never interacts with you  at  all,
          and  makes  the  default  answers  be used for all questions. It
          might mail error messages to root, but that's it;  otherwise  it
          is  completely  silent  and  unobtrusive, a perfect frontend for
          automatic installs. If you are using this front-end, and require
          non-default  answers  to questions, you will need to preseed the
          debconf database; see the section below  on  Unattended  Package
          Installation for more details.
```